# Windows security popup while installation of drivers

Tags: driver, installshield, windows-security

I'm getting Windows security popup while installing kernel driver using my installer. In previous builds, we were not getting this issue. But with our latest builds, we are getting this issue. We are signing our drivers with a proper certificate. I'm not getting why this security popup is coming while installation of drivers.

[image: Windows Security Popup]

Comment: What happens when you click "See details"? Any clues there?

Comment: What do you mean by a "proper" certificate? Is the target machine fully updated, or, say, a freshly installed VM? Is the behavior different on more recent versions of Windows than the pictured Windows 7, if the driver can be installed there?